# Is writing a new file to disk every second (or less occasionally) a risk for the hardware?

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm looking in to writing a network library that maintains a disk backed network queue of packets that need to be sent over to a server in case of network and/or power failure on the device. The device is writing a packet every second for up to days at a time. I want to store this packet and all unsent packets in a file on the device. The obvious and easy solution is to re-write the file whenever a new packet is received and whenever a packet is sent. I'm aware of the possible performance issues with this solution, but should I be concerned about the hardware with this solution as well? Or are the writes infrequent enough that it is negligible?

Comment: You probably need to quantify what the hardware actually is. Manufacturers usually provide expected-lifetime metrics for this kind of thing. I will say that you'd probably be better served by implementing redundancy in some other manner, as existing products do. Network failure is already trivially managed in software, and power failure should be mitigated against using a redundant power supply (e.g. UPS). Then you won't murder your hard drive and cripple your performance... Even better if you can make your application be able to recover from such a loss.

Comment: How important is it to back up the data *every second*? If this is a hard requirement I would rather look into protocol changes, such that the *protocol* is embedding some kind of redundancy mechanism for replaying the lost data.

Comment: Writing every second, every 100, every 0.01, etc. should be driven by the software requirements - and perhaps made configurable.  I doubt this concern is the most likely failure mechanism for a HD - it depends on too many unknowns here to answer well.

Comment: What is the OS? Do you fsync?

Comment: What kind of application? How many millions of US$ or human lifes are lost when one failure happens?

Comment: In terms of my use case, it is a large machine that runs tests on parts and collects data from sensors. These data points are collected every second, and are being sent to a server. The point of this project *is* to back the data up in case of a failure. I definitely could have been more specific describing this. In terms of hardware, It's just a standard desktop computer. I'm not sure of the exact specifications, but we can assume it is an HDD or SSD being written to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to the file every second will not increase the probability of the system failure unless you plan to write to SD card. Computers write data very frequently and one additional write every second will not have any significant effect on the system lifetime.

As other colleagues stated - if the information is important you should backup it.

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that most data writes are cached, and for the OP's use case they would presumably wish to flush the writes every time (there's no point in any of this if the writes are just going to sit in software anyway). That's going to have an impact that differs from the usual wear pattern.

Comment: We sell logging devices writing data eve much more frequently (even using SSDs). I do not see any problems even in a quite long perspective.  Of course, every disc eventually will die, and some get damaged because of the statistical probability of the failure.

Comment: I don't disagree, but do those devices force-flush every line when it's generated? I'm just saying, this needs to be taken into account in your calculations.

Comment: Everything on the disc has to be up to date. Otherwise, any other hardware problem will cause some data loss.

Answer (score -1):

> Is writing a new file to disk every second (or less occasionally) a risk for the hardware?

Of course yes. Hardware fails. Computers (and their data) can rust, or be destroyed (by cosmic rays, explosion, fire, bugs, software viruses, human errors or malice, etc....)

#### If the data is very important, you need to backup it periodically

On Linux, you might use some [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry, perhaps running `rsync` or `scp`, to backup your data on some remote site.

### Any kind of disk will eventually fail.

You may want to pay more for a a more reliable hard disk. You may want to pay more to have some [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) on your computer. You may want to have a [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID).

Some [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) disks are sold with some [MTBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) specification. Some expensive computers have some guaranteed MTBF. Rotating hard disks are rumored to fail more in vibrating conditions (e.g. inside an aircraft, a ship, a truck, an automobile or a robot), and on extreme temperature (e.g. below 10°C, or above 45°C).

Another possibility could be to make some SQL request to some *distant* [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) server, or even several of them. Doing that once per second is quite common.

Comment: Good answer..... It also address the larger issues.

Comment: Your answer focuses on mitigation for disk failure, not on the OP's solution's impact on the probability of _causing_ such a failure. It's an answer to a completely different question. Sorry.

Comment: `Any kind of disk will eventually fail.` it is something obvious. But writing some data to the disc every second will not be a source of quicker falure.

Comment: I think it depends if the disk is mechanical or SSD.

Comment: It depends on whether this disk is dedicated for this function or not. If it is, then these writes will be *the only* (or very significant) determining factor.

Comment: SSDs are quite smart. From my experience in the logging systems, the lifetime is almost the same. HDDs have more mechanical failures.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Maybe it addresses the larger issues, but it doesn't address the actual issue in question

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Re [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598786/is-writing-a-new-file-to-disk-every-second-or-less-occasionally-a-risk-for-the/65598828?noredirect=1#comment115980702_65598828) best removed as it a comment about the poster and not about the answer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No it isn't.